# Breakpoints in dynamically loaded jQuery

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I am trying to debug some javascript in chrome that is loaded dynamically.  I tried following the directions [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints), but it seems outdated.  The scripts tab is now called sources, and I can't seem to find dynamicScript.js even after I press the button.

Can I see dynamically loaded js from the sources tab?

Comment: did you try adding `debugger` in your code?

Comment: This works.  Why does it only list it when using that keyword?

Comment: don't understand what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually they are there. Press the [image], and viola.

[image]

In [this example,](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/gjf8e/) I dynamically included `jquery.easing`. They hide it just so there won't be a bunch of tabs on the bar.

### Update

[Their example](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints) is not working. (They might have moved this page from somewhere else?)

[image]

As you can see, `dynamicScript.js` is not loaded due to [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). They tried to load the script from `google.com` to `appspot.com`, which is not allowed. Notice their example is actually in `appspot.com`, not `google.com`. (Don't know why they do that.)

Comment: When doing the example, I can not find dynamicScript.js even if I expand that tab.  Could it be external scripts show, but ones loaded from the same site do not? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints

Comment: @Lumpy - It should work. If it does not: 1. You have not include your script; 2. You opened the developer tools before the script is loaded.

Comment: did you look at the google page I linked to.  They have a working example, but I can't find their script in my list.

Comment: @Lumpy - OK. I took a look in their example. And I found that `dynamicScript.js` could not be loaded due to the Cross-Domain Policy. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints-files/dynamicScript.js. Origin https://google-developers.appspot.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`